How to Add Custom Validation to a collection Property
I'm attempting to create a custom validation property that ensures that there is at least one selected property in a collection of complex objects. The server-side validation works fine but it appears the AddValidation method never fires, confirmed by setting break point on the method. As such the client side data attributes are never rendered to enable client side validation
Validator
 public class RequiredAtLeasOneFromCollectionAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
 {
     public RequiredAtLeasOneFromCollectionAttribute()
     {
         ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one"; //used if error message is not set on attribute itself
     }

     protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
     {
         List<object>  list = value as List<object>;

         if (list.IsNull() || !list.Any(x => x.IsSelected))
         {
             return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
         }

         return ValidationResult.Success;
     }

     public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
     {
         MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
         var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
         MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-requiredonefromcollection", errorMessage);
     }

     private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
     {
         if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
         {
             return false;
         }

         attributes.Add(key, value);
         return true;
     }
 }

CampgainType
 public class CampaignType
 {
     [Required]
     public int CampaignTypeId { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string CampaignTypeName { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = true;
 }

Consumer
public class Affiliate
 {
     [Required]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     
     [RequiredAtLeasOneFromCollectionAttribute]
     List<Campaigns> Campaigns {get; set}

     //Assume Constructor fills Campaigns 
}

CSHTML
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Affiliate.Campaigns.Count; i++)
{
    <div class='form-check'>
       <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Affiliate.Campaigns[i].CampaignId" />
       <input asp-for="@Model.Affiliate.Campaigns[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
       <label asp-for="@Model.Affiliate.Campaigns[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-label">@Model.Affiliate.Campaigns[i].CampaignTypeName </label>
    </div>            
}
<span asp-validation-for="Affiliate.Campaigns" class="text-danger"></span>

Visually the list/checkboxes render as expected, just the data attributes to hook into Unobtrusive validation is missing.

List<Campaigns> is not a List<object>. [but it is an IList or IEnumerable<object>] This is a variance issue.

In my opinion, the AddValidation is called when the taghelper for the input is rendered, since your input is for  @Model.Affiliate.Campaigns[i].IsSelected which is IsSelected property not the Campaigns which caused the AddValidation not called.
